# Practically safe to assume sizeof(std::unordered_map<std::string, T>) is the same for all T?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-lawyer

I'm in a situation where I have a circular dependency loop between the definitions of two classes, where (as far as I can tell) both classes need the other type to be a complete type in order to define them properly.

In simplified terms, what I need simplified version of what is going on:

```
struct Map;

struct Node {
    // some interface...
private:
    // this cannot be done because Map is an incomplete type
    char buffer[sizeof(Map)];
    // plus other stuff...
    void* dummy;
};

struct Map {
    // some interface...
private:
    // this is Map's only member
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Node> map_;
};
```

The situation is actually more complicated than the above, since `Node` is actually going to be a variant type (similar to `boost::variant`) that uses placement new to explicitly construct one of multiple types of objects in an preallocated (and with proper alignment, which I'm ignoring in this simplification) buffer: the buffer is therefore not exactly `sizeof(Map)` but rather some calculated constant that is dependent on `sizeof(Map)`.

The problem, obviously, is that `sizeof(Map)` is not available when `Map` is only forward declared. Furthermore, if I change the order of the declarations to forward declare `Node` first, then compilation of `Map` fails, as `std::unordered_map<std::string, Node>` cannot be instantiated when `Node` is an incomplete type, at least with my GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu. (I know it depends on the libstdc++ version more than the GCC version, but I don't know easily how to find that...)

As an alternative, I'm considering the following workaround:

```
struct Node {
    // some interface...
private:
    // doing this instead of depending on sizeof(Map)
    char buffer[sizeof(std::unordered_map<std::string, void*>)];
    // other stuff...
    void* dummy;
};

struct Map {
    // some interface...
private:
    // this is Map's only member
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Node> map_;
};

// and asserting this after the fact to make sure buffer is large enough
static_assert (sizeof(Map) <= sizeof(std::unordered_map<std::string, void*>),
    "Map is unexpectedly too large");
```

This basically relies on the assumption that `std::unordered_map<std::string, T>` is the same size for all T, which seems to hold true from my testing using GCC.

My question is thus threefold:

- Is there anything in the C++ standard that requires that this assumption to hold true? (I'm assuming no, but if there is I would be pleasantly surprised...)
- If not, is it *practically* safe to assume it holds true for all reasonable implementations anyway, and that the static assertion in my revised version will never fire?
- Finally, is there a better workaround to this issue that I haven't thought of? I'm sure it's possible there's something obvious I can do instead that I haven't thought of, but unfortunately I can't think of anything...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77815/discussion-on-question-by-trantorian-practically-safe-to-assume-sizeofstdunor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go ahead and assume.  Then `static_assert` at construction that you are right.

There are fancier solutions, like figuring out how boost recursive data structures work and applying the technique here (which might require writing your own map), or just using a `boost::` container that supports incomplete data structures.

Comment: I accepted this for now since you're the only person not telling me to use extra indirection (which is not really a solution to the problem, just avoiding it). I'd be curious if you could elaborate on recursive data structures, though--I'm guessing it's some way to take advantage of deferred template name binding to allow for structures with mutually dependent types?

Comment: @tran like how recursive optional works.  Some tag that the template knows refers to itself.

Comment: okay, thanks, I think I get the idea. maybe something like that will help--I'll keep the `static_assert` version for now while and think about something like that as an alternative in the background

Answer (score 3):

1) No

2) STL containers cannot be instantiated with an incomplete type. However, apparently some compilers do allow this. Not allowing this wasn't a trivial decision and in many cases your assumption will indeed hold true. [This](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814) article might interest you. Given the fact that according to the standard this problem is not solvable without adding a layer of indirection and you don't want to do that. I just have to give a heads up you are indeed not doing things according to the standard.

Having said that, I think that your solution is the best one using stl containers. And the static assert will indeed warn when the size does indeed exceed the expected size.

3) Yes with adding another layer of indirection, my solution would be the following:

The problem you have is that the size of an object, depends on the size of its arrays. Say you have an object A and and object B:

```
struct A
{
   char sizeof[B]
}

struct B
{
    char sizeof[A]
}
```

Object A will grow, in order to house chars for the size of B. But then in turn object B will have to grow. I guess you can see where this is going. I know this is your exact problem, but I think the underlying principles are pretty similar.

In this particular case I would solve it by changing the

```
char buffer[sizeof(Map)];
```

Line to be just a pointer:

```
char* buffer
```

And dynamically allocate memory after initialization. Sow your cpp file would look something like this:

```
//node.cpp
//untested code
node::node()
{
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(map));
}

node::~node()
{
    free buffer;
}
```

Comment: No, `Map` contains `std::unordered_map<std::string, Node>`, not `Node` directly, and the former does not actually grow with the size of `Node`, so this case is not like the case you are saying. Practically, `std::unordered_map<std::string, Node>` does not actually change size as `Node` changes, because it does not directly contain a `Node`; any implementation for which the size does change based on the `value_type` parameter must be doing some strange optimization which I'm trying to rule out _practically_ happening in practice.

Comment: Also, I do not want to dynamically allocate memory like you are saying, because it adds an extra layer of indirection. See the discussion in the comments on the question for more explanation.

Comment: @Trantorian Officially any specialization declaration made with a type, requires a full type. It might be true that `unordered_map` does not actually change size. But I would still rather not go there. Meaning you have to implement either class without a full type. This is simply a requirement of c++, you cannot declare two classes dependent on eachothers full type. I'm afraid the only way of getting around this as far as i know, is indeed adding another layer of indirection.

Comment: @Trantorian Also, a layer of indirection is not a horrible thing. At least it in my opinion it's rather less horrible than relying on code that seems to work. But isn't according to the standard.

Comment: @Trantorian Oh and one other thing. The difference between a pointer and an array is not all that big. They can in most cases be regarded as the same.

Comment: Well, it's guaranteed to work if the static_assert succeeds. And there's really no practical implementation reason I can think of for the `unordered_map` to change size.

Comment: You're missing that `Node` is a union of different value types that will be accessible via template metaprogramming though. I can't make one indirect without making them all indirect, and having an `std::vector` of `Node`s each of which indirectly owns a primitive is too costly by far. `Node`s containing `Map`s will be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @Trantorian Okay I see, that is actually a very interesting problem then:). Allow me some time to think it over. Sorry it toke me some time to get there;)

Comment: @Trantorian Well this is interesting. I'm doing some testing and in the msvc2013 compiler, it is allowed to create stl containers of incomplete types. That's something I didn't know...

Answer (score 1):

1) No

2) I'm not sure

3) You may also use design pattern **Factory method**. Your factory will return object based on `Map` variant ( EDIT: I mean you will use Map variant instance as parameter and Factory method implementation will use that information to create return object accordingly) and it can preallocate buffer to correct size.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are suggesting with 3)? In particular, I don't want extra indirection through pointers than what I have in the revised version (which works when the `static_assert` passes). `Node` is effectively a union that contains one of a variety of types without indirection, and the list of possible types includes `Map`, `std::string`, and `bool`.

Comment: One of your `Node` instance will return one type at life time or it will vary? And are you familiar with design patterns?

Comment: I will have only one type at a time, but it can change. If the type is changed, then the `Node` will explicitly call the right type destructor on the current contents and placement-new an object of the new type, updating a type tag in the process. I am familiar with design patterns but don't see what you mean--in particular, it seems like you are suggesting that the factory will return some generic pointer type, like `void*` to avoid `Node` depending on the size of `Map`; this is exactly what I don't want because the extra indirection will add up quickly as this is a recursive structure.

Comment: Well, since I don't see purpose of having char buffer with variable size instead of reference to `Map` instance with getting data from that instance, I can only suggest Decorator to change `Node`.

Comment: Because what you're suggesting adds an extra layer of indirection which I absolutely don't want. The char buffer there is because I want `Node` to store objects directly inside of it: `Node` might contain `std::string`, `bool`, or one of another of types: the idea is to have a properly aligned buffer large enough to hold the largest one, which might in fact end up being `Map`. What you're suggesting makes every step of recursively iterating through this structure require more indirection.

Comment: So you have some tree structure with `Node` instances refers to others and all instances will hold `Map` data, right?

Comment: No, some `Node`s will have a `Map`, and some will have a `bool`, `std::string`, or `Array`, etc. `Node` is basically a union, except using placement-new and explicit destructor calls to manipulate C++ types and ensure that there's no undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

1) Probably not

2) Since it looks like it's totally dependent on implementation, that's a big risk as this can literally break at any compiler update.

3) You can use [`boost::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) which will accept incomplete types and thus will solve your problem.